# How to access JSON data using d3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a JSON data type which I am storing in my model to pass to the view. I also have a bar chart which I would like to use to display the data. However, there are only some fields which I would like to display which are the SupplierName and the Query. I've followed through a d3 tutorial to get the graph but this is the first time I'm putting it into practice.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult ValueBySupplierAndClaimType(int ClientID, int ReviewPeriodID, int StatusCategoryID) {
            ValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeViewModel model = new ValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeViewModel {
                ReportData = reportRepo.GetValueBySupplierAndClaimType(ClientID, ReviewPeriodID, StatusCategoryID),
                ReportTitle = "Dashboard Breakdown",
                ReportDescription = "Breakdown for " + reviewRepo.GetAllReviewsByClientID(ClientID).Where(r => r.ReviewID == ReviewPeriodID).Select(r => r.ReviewPeriod).FirstOrDefault()
            };

            model.output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.ReportData, Formatting.Indented);

            return View("ValueBySupplierAndClaimType", model);
```

JSON:

```
[  
  {
    "SupplierID": 4336,
    "SupplierName": "Test1",
    "AccountNo": 09579
    "Claim": null,
    "Normal": null,
    "Query": 1000.0000,
    "Formal": null,
    "Strong": null,
    "Unsubstantiated": null
  },
  {
    "SupplierID": 4357,
    "SupplierName": "Test2                 ",
    "AccountNo": 00124
    "Claim": null,
    "Normal": null,
    "Query": 9000.0000,
    "Formal": null,
    "Strong": null,
    "Unsubstantiated": null
  },
  {
    "SupplierID": 4395,
    "SupplierName": "Test3                   ",
    "AccountNo": 00001
    "Claim": null,
    "Normal": null,
    "Query": null,
    "Formal": null,
    "Strong": null,
    "Unsubstantiated": null
  }
]
```

D3:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```

```
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10, "%");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv(@Model.output, type, function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        data.forEach(function(d) {

            //(function(d) {return d.SupplierName})
            //(function(d) {return d.Query})

            x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.SupplierName }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Query })]);

        })


        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Query");

        svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.SupplierName); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.Query); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.Query); });
    });

    function type(d) {
        d.Query = +d.Query;
        return d;
    }


</script>
```

I've tried looking at some answers but and have tried to implement them but nothing has seemed to work

Comment: The "CSV" looks like JSON to me: `d3.json(...)`

Comment: are there still any problems with your question? please leave me a comment. If my answer solved your problem you [should accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). that way others can see that your problem is solved and which answer did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

**JSON**

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` returns a JSON (as the name may indicate) and not an CSV. Therefore you should use `d3.json`, but

**Request**

`d3.csv` and `d3.json` take an [URL as first parameter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) and fire an XMLHttpRequest to get the data, parse the data when loaded an pass it to the callback.

Your `@Model.output` holds a string with the full JSON. You don't need to request the data since you already have it as string. You only have to parse the string with `JSON.parse()` like so:

```
...
//d3.csv(@Model.output, type, function (error, data) {
try {
  var data = JSON.parse("@Model.output");

  data.forEach(function(d){
    x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.SupplierName }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Query })]);
  });
  ...
} catch(e){
  ...
}
```

Make sure to use try-catch since JSON.parse could fail with an invalid JSON.